# OpenCL image objects and bounds checking

Tags: opencl

What's the purpose of having OpenCL image object checking bounds during reads when I have to do it manually anyways during writes?

Let's say I have a kernel performing a simple transformation of an image into an image of the same dimensions. 
Since I need to make global_work_size a multiple of local_work_size (I'm using OpenCL), there will be some work-items that are there just for the padding and aren't doing any valuable work. 
Conditional branching generally slows execution down so image2d_t objects are supposed to help with this by performing automatic bounds checking.

Yet, seemingly I have to do manual bound checks anyways when writing back to another image lest I risk undefined behavior, so why not just do the check at the beginning and exclude reads as well for out-of-bounds work-items.

```
__kernel void check_at_write (__read_only image2d_t input,
                   __write_only image2d_t output
                   int width, int height)
{
    /* declarations of sampler, indexes */

    /* imagine we're only doing 
     * a simple map with foo
     * for the sake of the example 
     */
    float4 res = foo(read_imagef(input, sampler, (int2)(index_x, index_y)));
    if (index_x < width && index_y < height)
        write_imagef(output, (int2)(index_x, index_y), res);
}

__kernel void check_at_read (__read_only image2d_t input,
                   __write_only image2d_t output
                   int width, int height)
{
    /* declarations of sampler, indexes */
    if (index_x < width && index_y < height) {
        float4 res = foo(read_imagef(input, sampler, (int2)(index_x, index_y)));
        write_imagef(output, (int2)(index_x, index_y), res);
    }
}
```

So why even have this mechanism of automatic checks during reads? Do I have a way to avoid checking altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image sizes match your global work size, no checking is needed for read or write. If they don't, add a single check around the whole kernel, then don't check on read or write (assuming they are the same location). In both cases use CLK_ADDRESS_NONE because it can be faster on some hardware (compared to the other modes). The place clamping (or mirroring or repeating) are handy are when your read location(s) differs from your write location (because maybe you're transforming the coordinate or reading a halo around the pixel location for filtering). In any case, it's in the hardware and OpenCL gives you access to it. I find it quite useful in our many image processing kernels.